# Parse elements of a std::string into integers (C++)

Tags: c++

I am getting an odd error in my code where I try to take the elements of a std::string and convert them into 2 seperate ints

An example of the string would be "A6". I would like to be able to convert this string into 2 integers. In this example, the integers would be 65 (because 'A' is 65 in the ASCII chart) and 6.

Currently this is the code:

```
    // Parse string into integers
    int tempRow = userGuess[0];
    
    int tempColumn = userGuess[1];

    std::cout << tempRow << tempColumn;
```

"A1" outputs 65 and 49.
Why does '1' become an integer of 49?

Comment: because ascii code for `1` is 49

Comment: Because the `[]` operator returns a char, and `49` is the ASCII code of the char `1`.

Comment: Because the ASCII code for `'1'` is `49`. Subtract `'0'` from it to get a proper number.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Is there a reason why  subtracting 0 from a character fixes this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ascii code for `1` is 49, which is the result you are assigning to `tempColumn`. If you want the integer value, you need to do:

```
int tempColumn = userGuess[1] - '0';
```

This subtracts the ascii version of `0` which is 48 from the integer.

Comment: Thanks. What's the logic behind subtracting '0'?

Comment: The ascii values of `0`, `1`, `2`, is 48, 49, 50 etc. Subtracting `0` gives you the result 0, 1, 2, etc.

Comment: @RudyGoburt Specifically, one of the few requirements that C++ has about legal character sets is that the digits `'0'` through `'9'` must be represented by consecutive values. The character `'0'` has some value, then `'1'` is required to be the value after `'0'` (or `'0' + 1`), `'2'` is one after that (or `'0' + 2`), etc. So no matter what encoding your platform uses, subtracting `'0'` from any of the 10 digit characters will always give you that digit's numeric value.